# Joomla content database change not reflected in article manager

Tags: database, joomla

I am programmatically ordering my article database by hits and featuring articles with high hit rates.

Joomla does not recognize that the articles are featured, although the database accurately reflects my changes.

Article manager does not recognize articles as featured (when I try to list only featured articles).  Yet, when I pull up an article for editing, it is clearly flagged as featured.  When I save the article through article manager, the featured attribute works as expected.

Does anyone have an idea what I am leaving undone?

Comment: This is a bit confusing because you are talking about ordering by hits (a standard option on any list view and doesn't require any database changes) and featuring (a totally separate field) . Lists are displayed in the order indicated when you create a menu item to display the list or in the absence of such a menu item, as set in the article global configuration for lists.

Comment: sorry to be confusing.  After ordering by hits, I go through the ordered list changing the first 30 featured fields to true, and the remaining to false.  While the database changes are evident, Article manager doesn't display the articles as featured, though the appear as featured when I edit the article from article manager.  After I resave the articles, everything works appropriately.

Comment: It's possibly just caching at work.  If you are doing that a lot I would write a cron job to automate it.

Comment: A cronjob is the intention -- twice a day.  Unfortunately, it does not appear to be a caching issue.  In 24 hours, the cache should have caught up with the state of the database.  After 24 hours, the database shows the top 30 articles as featured, but Article Manager and Joomla don't recognize the change in the featured field until the database is updated through Article Manager ... not my php program.

Comment: First you should write a joomla cli to do it. Without that i have no idea if you have done all the changes in multiple tables that are needed for featuring. YOu need to show the code otherwise honestly I'm assuming you are just changing `#__content` and that is why it's not working as you expect.

Comment: Thanks Elin!  Your assumption was correct and I was only changing #___content.  You have pointed me in an unknown direction with joomla cli's.  Thanks!